# Proving subset is not connected iff there exist open sets in X

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, connectedness

Prove that E $\subseteq$ X is not connected if and only if there exist **open** sets $A, B \subseteq X$ such that $E \subseteq A ∪ B, A ∩ B$ = $\emptyset$ and $E ∩ A$ and $E ∩ B$ are both nonempty.

$X$ is a nonempty set equipped with a metric d.

Having a hard time proving the ⇒ part of the proof. Help!

Comment: What is the definition of connectedness in this context?  In some books, the right half is used as a definition.

Comment: I think you have the cap and cup the wrong way round as if $A\cup B=\emptyset$, then $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Comment: @Joel: Only definition I have is E is connected if E is not a union of two non-empty, separated sets.

Comment: Dan, you are of course right...sorry for the typo. I've changed it.

Comment: Well, if by 'separated' you meant 'disjoint', then this definition is not good, as then no space with $\ge 2$ points would be connected.. The exercise is basically the right definition.

Comment: What you are asked to prove is the most popular (and in my opinion, the best) _definition_ of a disconnected set.  I'm not sure how you can "prove" it!  Your professor must be using a different (but equivalent) definition or else s/he would not have assigned this problem.  What does "separated" mean in your comment above?

Comment: Ok, for separated, I have two subsets A and B of a metric space are separated if no point of A lies in the closure of B and no point of B lies in the closure of A, which seems to be saying that the two sets are disjoint.

Comment: See also:  [Prove that $E$ is disconnected iff there exists two open disjoint sets $A$,$B$ in $X$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/688183/prove-that-e-is-disconnected-iff-there-exists-two-open-disjoint-sets-a-b-i)